# Firefox Addon SDK: is it possible to show another panel from another .js

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm showing a panel from `main.js`

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
            var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
            width: 570,
            height: 230,
            contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("content.html")
            });
            panel.show();
       }, true)
```

Now, I want to show another panel from `another.js`

```
function myFunction(){
    setTimeout(function(){

        var data = require('self').data;
        var reminder_panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
          width: 570,
          height: 230,
          contentURL:"http://www.google.com"
          });
         reminder_panel.show();
    },4000);
}
```

But it's not working. I'm newbie in Firefox addon development. Any help would be great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Add-on SDK 'main.js' is the only script that is run by default. If you want to run code in other scripts in the add-on's lib directory you would need to require the other script:

'another.js':

```
function myFunction(){
    setTimeout(function(){

        var data = require('self').data;
        var reminder_panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
          width: 570,
          height: 230,
          contentURL:"http://www.google.com"
          });
         reminder_panel.show();
    },4000);
}

exports.myFunction = myFunction; // export the function
```

'main.js':

```
var another = require('another');

another.myFunction(); // the panel will show.
```

Please see the docs for more background information on how CommonJS modules are used in the Add-on SDK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/modules.html